# onClickActionListener Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

This is my code on Android I am fairly new at Android, this is my `onClick` method.
Whenever I run this app, and click the button. It says "WordCounterApp has stopped working". This app is for counting how many words a user has imputed can any one help?

```
package com.example.wordcountapp;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView2;
    private Button button1;
    private EditText editText1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = editText1.getText().toString();
                String input = str; 
                int wordCount =  -1;
                String array[] = input.trim().split(" ");
                if( "".equals(input) ||
                    "\n".equals(input)) {
                    wordCount = 0;
                }
                else{
                    wordCount = array.length;
                }
                textView2.setText(wordCount);   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
 textView2.setText(""+wordCount);
```

**OR**

```
 textView2.setText(String.valueOf(wordCount));
```

instead of

```
 textView2.setText(wordCount);
```

because you can not set Int directly to TextView you will need to convert it to String first

Comment: +1 for `String.valueOf(...)` but personally I dislike the `""+wordCount` way of doing it. It's a bit of a hack but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the value of an text view to an int, instead of `textview.setText(wordCount)` use `textview.setText(Integer.toString(wordCount);`